# a function is required to be static in java

Tags: java, static

The following block has an error. It requires the createArrayList function to be static. I cannot understand the reason. I appreciate if anyone can explains that to me in an understandable way.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Ceasefire {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        createArrayList();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public void createArrayList()
    {
        ArrayList<String> aL1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        aL1.add("Item1");
        aL1.add("Item2");
        aL1.add("Item3");
        System.out.println(aL1);    
    }
}
```

Comment: You've misread what the exception actually says. It doesn't 'require the `createArrayList()` function to be static'. It just says you can't call it from a non-static context.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a **non-static** (`createArrayList`) method from a static one (`main`). A `static` method can only call other `static` methods, but no instance methods.